# Spring Boot Admin client gets exception during initialization

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Just upgraded Spring Boot Admin server and client. Server starts up fine. When I start a client I get the following exception.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registrator' defined in class path resource [de/codecentric/boot/admin/client/config/SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator]: Factory method 'registrator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lorg/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder;

I suspect the issue is with Spring Rest, but I dont know why. Is that something you might be able to help me with?

Here are the versions I am using.

```xml
<spring-boot-dependencies.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-boot-dependencies.version>
<spring.version>5.1.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

```xml
<spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.4</spring-boot-admin.version>
```

Client Configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class AdminPanelConfigurationDefault
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminPanelConfigurationDefault.class);

    @Bean
    public ApplicationFactory applicationFactory(InstanceProperties instance,
            ManagementServerProperties management,
            ServerProperties server,
            ServletContext servletContext,
            PathMappedEndpoints pathMappedEndpoints,
            WebEndpointProperties webEndpoint,
            MetadataContributor metadataContributor,
            DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath,
            @Qualifier(CommonApplicationConfig.RUNNING_APP_BEAN_NAME) Application application)
    {
        String applicationURL = application.getUrl();
        logger.debug("Setting serviceBaseUrl to {} from the app table", applicationURL);

        instance.setServiceUrl(applicationURL);

        return new ServletApplicationFactory(instance, management, server, servletContext, pathMappedEndpoints,
                webEndpoint, metadataContributor, dispatcherServletPath);
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any advice you can offer. Thanks.